# Can imported flowers be used to decorate God?

Tags: worship, customs

I live in Australia. The management committee of Lord Siva Temple here imports flower garland from India. After the arrival The Australian quarantine department spray chemicals on garland to stop any insects spreading.

Please let us know that can we use these garlands for God?

Comment: Flowers offered to god must be ideally freshly plucked and offered immediately taking care not to place it on the floor, change too many hands etc. Flowers that have "slept overnight" are considered unusable. Why doesn't your temple start a small flower garden and use those flowers?

Comment: why not use flowers from Australia???

Comment: @moonstar2001 I think the flowers that are bought are exempt from that "freshness" rule. However for temples having a flower garden is quite an usual thing.

Comment: @Rickross No, they are not exempt. It is just that   one cannot guarantee the freshness of bought flowers and bought flowers are better than no flowers. Bought flowers are not considered uttama offering.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Do have any reference to prove that? I know that articles that are sold are considered as pure. But spraying chemicals is of course not recommended.

Comment: @Rickross Do you have any reference to prove that bought flowers are exempt from freshness rule?

Comment: @moonstar2001 Anything that are offered on sale are to be considered as pure. We shouldn't be bothered about their purity, be it flowers or anything else. And yes i can prove that from Smritis.

Comment: @Rickross That is not the case when offering flowers in puja. Bought flowers are madhyama or adhama offering; not uttama.  Again in the last comment you speak of purity not freshness. So you are contradictin g yourself?

Comment: @moonstar2001 The flowers that are bought from vendors can be used in Puja without considering the purity/freshness aspect. that is what i meant. In case of plucked flowers they can't be used the day next to when they were plucked. For bought flowers there are no such restrictions.

Comment: @Rickross So bought flowers are not plucked flowers? We should offer fresh flowers only. If you say stale flowers can be offered to god, that is not right. Only few flowers have an exception of using. Tulasi is one of them. We must always use fresh flowers to the god.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that still i'm not cleared.
Can we offer chemical sprayed garlands to God or not?
Thanks.

Comment: @Rickross That makes bought flowers superior to plucked ones and this is incorrect.

Comment: @Madhanagopal The question really is stale flowers not just sprayed flowers. Even if your government did not bathe the flowers in chemicals, those flowers are still inferior offerings. Plant a garden.

Comment: @moonstar2001 No it does not make bought flowers superior.. Its just that they are not rendered stale or impure like the plucked flowers are..

Comment: @SreeCharan Bilva, Tulasi can be reused .. and they retain their purity for many days since they are plucked from the trees.. In case of flowers that we pluck ourselves ( not  bought in exchange of money) , they should be offered on that day itself.. but flowers that are bought don't have any such restrictions. Now whether plucked fresh flowers should only be offered or not is a different question..

Comment: Yes you can use it. Remember he is a god stays in cremation, he never sees what you give but it matters how you give.